# How do I handle a .ashx Generic Handler page in Blazor?

Tags: razor, blazor, ashx

I am replacing a Project built using ASP.NET WebForms and I need to replace the .ashx Generic Handlers - but I need to keep the page names so an app that has these URIs hardcoded does not require updating.

I know how to deal with the logic, that is not the problem.  The problem is that these pages are referenced by an app that I do not want to update, so I need to be able to use URIs that point to pages ending in .ashx.

I have tried everything I can think of.  I had hoped to just use the @page directive as shown below:

@page "/mygenerichandler.ashx"

Unfortunately, that does not work.  If it did, I would be all set.

I have seen pages telling me to handle the .ashx as a sort of parameter:

@page "/mygenerichandler/{ashx}"  (and variations of this, none work)

This does not work.

I have tried just naming the pages with the .ashx extension.  This does not work.

I do not want to have to update the apps that have the URLs embedded in them, but it is looking more and more like that is my only option.

Is there any way to accept a page request in Blazor to a page that is named something like "mygenerichandler.ashx"?

Comment: If this is server side, then you should look into adding Middleware.  This allows you to intercept any and all requests to your site, and pretty much do whatever you want with them.  This occurs before the request ever hits Blazor.  I'm reasonably sure you can still keep the original address, even in the URL in the browser, while serving an entirely differnet page.

Comment: Thanks for the response, much appreciated!   My specific issue is the name of the file itself.  My existing desktop apps all have .ashx pages hardcoded.  I need to be able to use these same URLs without modification.  What you suggest is what I should do inside the Razor Pages, I am talking about getting to the page itself via a URI that Blazor will not handle.  How do I get Blazor to respond to calls to pages with a .ashx extension?

Comment: I have yet to find a means by which to do this with the .ashx files.  I cannot get anything but a 'page not found' response.  I suspected that what you said is how it is done, but cannot get it to 'see' the pages with a .ashx extension.

Comment: Somehow I managed to find this page:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-7.0#migrating-handler-code-to-middleware

I think it might be the answer.  I plan to review it and see if that resolves the routing issue.  The rest is exactly what Bennyboy mentioned - the need for Middleware.  I need to figure all that out once I get the .ashx path issues resolved.

Comment: You could try here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-7.0  Apparently .net already includes pre-made middleware that you might be able to leverage.  Also (not sure if I'm allowed to say this) rare tasks like this are sometimes a good use case for chatGPT-- it almost never gives fully functional code, but it usually reveals libraries or other techniques that can set you on the right path.

Comment: Looks like that Fundamentals link may be the key.  And yes, chatGPT is indeed a useful tool for clear explanations of things or examples of how to do things.  I have been using it a fair amount and for the most part like it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I am using the Middleware Pattern, and it turns out that this will execute early in the pipeline and allow me to inspect the URL for the .ashx extension and then route accordingly.  I should be able to return a response from this point - I still have to implement that code, but it is not directly germane to this question so I will not cover it here.

```
public class HandlerTrapper
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        
        public string? AccountID { get; set; }

        public HandlerTrapper(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)  //, [FromQuery(Name = "AccountID")] string accountId
        {           

            string? page = httpContext.Request.Path.Value?.Replace(@"/", "");

            Console.WriteLine("Page Name is {0}, AccountID = {1}", page, AccountID);

            if(page==null || !page.Contains(".ashx"))
                return _next(httpContext);

            AccountID = httpContext.Request.Query["AccountID"];

            switch (page)
            {
                case "GetAmzRefreshToken":

                    break;
            }

            return _next(httpContext);
        }

        private 
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class HandlerTrapperExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseHandlerTrapper(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<HandlerTrapper>();
        }
    }
```

This is called as shown here in Program.cs:

```
app.UseHandlerTrapper();
```

I am pretty sure I can just return a Response from here and after implementing the code that does the work based on the incoming legacy page name, I should have a replacement for my .ashx Generic Handlers.

Comment: For people getting to this answer ... I'm fairly certain you would not want to call return _next(httpContext) ... as that would allow the rest of the pipeline processes to attempt to resolve the url in question.

Answer (score 0):

There is an even better solution which I implemented in my code.  The WebApplication class has a UrlReWriter method that solves this problem quite elegantly when used in conjunction with the Controller Routing.

I added these lines to my Program.cs file - I placed them before the UseHttpRedirection and the UseRouting calls.:

```
    RewriteOptions urlOptions = new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite(@"^(.*).ashx$", "api/$1", false);

    urlOptions.AddRewrite(@"^(.*).inf$", "api/ComputerInfo", false);

    app.UseRewriter(urlOptions);
```

That resolved the issue for both of the file type patterns I needed to handle, and I can add more if need be.